# Array covariance in F#

Tags: .net, arrays, f#, covariance

Since .NET arrays are covariant, the following works in C#:

```
var strArray = new string[0];
object[] objArray = strArray;
```

In F#, given an array, `'T[]`, what would be the best way to convert it to `obj[]`, without re-creating the array (e.g., `Array.map box`)? I'm using `(box >> unbox)`, but it feels sloppy.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know this about C#. Isn't this quite a misfeature, compromising static type safety?

Comment: @wmeyer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3516619/162396; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx

Comment: I actually find it very useful for generic classes implementing non-generic interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
box >> unbox
```

seems like a good idea; O(1), and does the job, apparently.

Consider also not using this CLR mis-feature.  ;)

Comment: I suppose I could use `Array.map box` but it feels wrong to re-create the array when a perfectly good misfeature is available. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

As Brian says, there's nothing wrong with `box >> unbox`, other that the fact that array covariance is inherently broken (e.g. `([| "test" |] |> box |> unbox<obj[]>).[0] <- obj()` will throw an ArrayTypeMismatchException when trying to perform the assignment).

Instead, you would probably be better off treating a `string[]` as an `obj seq`, which is perfectly safe (although it still requires boxing and unboxing in F# since F# doesn't support generic co/contra-variance).  Unfortunately, you do lose random access if you go this route.

Comment: And unfortunately I need random access. Maybe the bigger question is how to implement a non-generic interface member of type array. My interface is a "paged list of items" (the items plus paging info). So the array element could be any type. Otherwise, I would invent yet another interface to represent the array elements. I guess that's the preferred solution.

Comment: @Daniel - ideally, the BCL would contain a `ReadOnlyArray<'t>` type which was covariant and which `'t[]` derived from.  Since it doesn't, you're limited to some less desirable options.  Using array covariance is fine as long as you remember never to write to the converted array...

Comment: I logged ReadOnlyArray, please vote for it!  http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2235515-readonly-array

Answer (score 3):

Brian's solution looks fine to me, but do you really need array covariance?

If you have a function that takes `ISomething[]` and want to pass it `SomeSomething[]` then you need it, but if the function only reads values of type `ISomething` from the array (which is what the covariance allows), then you could use hash-type and write a function that takes `#ISomething[]`. (Assuming that you can modify the function, of course!)

This way, the function can work on array of any elements that implement `ISomething` and you don't need array covariance when calling it. Here is an example:

```
type A() = 
  interface IDisposable with 
    member x.Dispose() = printfn "gone"

// Disposes the first element from an array
let disposeFirst (a:#IDisposable[]) = a.[0].Dispose()

// Call 'disposeFirst' with 'A[]' as an argument
let aa = [| new A(); new A() |]
disposeFirst aa
```

It seems to me that the main reason for array covariance in .NET is that it was needed at the time when generics did not exist, but it seems that F# can live without this feature just fine.

Comment: How would you implement an interface member returning `obj[]` with a generic type having member of type `'T[]`? The interface doesn't know about `'T`, so I don't see how hash types will help.

Comment: @Daniel - I'm not sure I understand the scenario. Can you give some example? A hash type makes the function generic and allows it to take not just `obj[]` but also `foo[]` where `foo` inherits from `obj`, which is the same thing as what array covariance does...

Comment: An interface (which isn't generic) has a member of type `obj[]`. The obstacle is that using a hash type makes the enclosing type generic. The class that implements the interface *is* generic, however (the corresponding member is of type `'T[]`).

Comment: @Daniel - oh, I see - you want to _set the value of a field_. I was (wrongly) assuming that you just want to call some function that takes `obj[]`. In that case, I think Brian's solution is the only reasonable option.