# Covariant behaviour of arrays when assigning to IList<T>

Tags: c#, arrays, covariance, ilist

I am wondering how an array has different behaviour to `List<T>`, both which implement IList, where the array appears to be getting around IList's non-covariant nature (it is not defined as `IList<out T>`), when assigning to `IList<IPerson>`.
In the below example all assignments are ok except for 'people3'. Why does the assignment work in the case of 'people4' for personArray?

```
public interface IPerson { }
public class Person : IPerson { }

var personList = new List<Person>();
var personArray = new Person[0];

IList<Person> people1 = personList;
IList<Person> people2 = personArray;
IList<IPerson> people3 = personList;
IList<IPerson> people4 = personArray;
```

Comment: [Not *totally* a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516619/why-are-c-sharp-arrays-covariant-and-what-benefits-does-it-bring) so I won't hammer it.

Comment: Somehow my attempts to find related questions missed that one

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx explains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because that kind of covariance is a bad thing and C# only supports it with arrays because Java supports it.

This gives a runtime error

```
        object[] myArray = new string[1];
        myArray[0] = 1;
```

This gives a compile time error

```
        List<object> myList = new List<string>(1);
        myList[0] = 1;
```

Comment: So do you think it 'is a bad thing' purely because of possible runtime assignment errors? Otherwise I like the free behaviour in the case of compatible sub class / base class.

Comment: In your original example you created a List<Person>.  If you intended it to be a List<IPerson> then you should have done that originally. By converting it to a List<IPerson> you are allowing something other than a Person to be added to the list.  This is prevented at compile time with lists, and at run time with arrays.  You do not actually have any more flexibility.

Comment: In that case I'm now inclined to use List<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>. :)

Answer (score 0):

If `T:U`, an instance to a `T[]` may be cast to `IList<U>`, but even though `IList<T>.IsReadOnly` will be false, `IList<U>.IsReadOnly` will return `true`.  Note that even though `IList<U>.IsReadOnly` returns `true`, attempts to write to the `IList<U>` may still succeed if the particular item being written happens to satisfy type `T`.  There is no way I know of to ascertain whether a particular instance identified by a `U` may be stored into an `ILIst<T>` except by trying it and observing if an exception occurs.